# What is a polymorphic clone operation and what are its advantages?

Tags: java

Joshua Bloch says [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)-

> But it doesn't say anything about what you can do with an object that
>   implements the Cloneable interface, which means that you can't do a
>   polymorphic clone operation.

Further,
protected allows access from subclasses and from other classes in the same package

Suppose-

```
package com.aa;
public class AA { 
    protected void testProcAA(){
        System.out.println("In AA");
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.bb;

import com.aa.AA;

public class BB extends AA {

    protected void testProcBB(){

    }

    public void show() {
        testProcBB();  // accessed through this

        testProcAA();  // accessed through this

        AA aa = new AA();
        aa.testProcAA();  // compile error- testProcAA() from the type AA is not visible

        AA aa1 = new BB();
        aa1.testProcAA(); // compile error- testProcAA() from the type AA is not visible
    }

}
```

By polymorphic cloning, does he means this(replacing `testProcAA` by name `clone`  ) -

```
AA aa1 = new BB();
aa1.testProcAA();
```

Comment: He explains it right there: `But it doesn't say anything about what you can do with an object that implements the Cloneable interface, which means that you can't do a polymorphic clone operation. If I have an array of Cloneable, you would think that I could run down that array and clone every element to make a deep copy of the array, but I can't. You cannot cast something to Cloneable and call the clone method, because Cloneable doesn't have a public clone method and neither does Object.`

Comment: There is no such thing as `polymorphic clone operation` Joshua explains why `clone` in Java is broken, one of the reasons is that it's not polymorphic.

Comment: @Oleg: But due to the protected access modifier used with clone method in Object class, the polymorphic beahvior  can't be achieved as evident.

Comment: Yes, and that is the problem.

Comment: @Oleg: I surmise that you edited your second last comment after my comment. ::))

Comment: Yeah, I mistyped it without the `no`